# Loop to copy results of filtered table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a work schedule, where I have a list of employees name and a flat table with everyone schedule per day. My macro should for each employee filter the data, copy it and paste it in a new sheet with his/her name.

```
Sub EnvoiPlanning()
    'Sheets("People").Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
        xlYes
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    While Sheets("People").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Sheets("Data").Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Sheets("People").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheets("Data").Range("A:F").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Sheets("People").Cells(2, 1).Value
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

There is error:

> Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed

on the second instruction of the loop after the first iteration.

[image: Exception screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Sub EnvoiPlanning()
    'Sheets("People").Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
        xlYes
    Dim i As Integer, _
        Ws As Worksheet
    i = 2
    While Sheets("People").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Sheets("Data").Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Sheets("People").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheets("Data").Range("A:F").Copy
        Set Ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        Ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                Operation:=xlNone, _
                                SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                Transpose:=False
        Ws.Name = Sheets("People").Cells(2, 1).Value
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```